# java.io.IOException: Stream closed During PDFbox setValue loop

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, pdfbox

So I am kind-a stuck in a strange situation, explained briefly, I have a web form that when filled fills a PDF template using PDFbox and saves it in given location. Now the App works fine in my eclipse environment but when I run it on a test tomcat server it fails with the following :

```
ERROR c.j.h.controller.HomeController - I=0   fields=FullName{type: PDTextField value: null}
ERROR c.j.h.controller.HomeController - I=0   fields=FullName{type: PDTextField value: COSString{fsdf}}
ERROR c.j.h.controller.HomeController - I=1   fields=Address{type: PDTextField value: null}
ERROR o.s.b.web.support.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/save] due to exception [java.io.IOException: Stream closed]
        java.lang.InternalError: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
                at sun.util.locale.provider.BreakIteratorProviderImpl.getBreakInstance(BreakIteratorProviderImpl.java:178)
                at sun.util.locale.provider.BreakIteratorProviderImpl.getLineInstance(BreakIteratorProviderImpl.java:106)
                at java.text.BreakIterator.createBreakInstance(BreakIterator.java:571)
                at java.text.BreakIterator.createBreakInstance(BreakIterator.java:553)
                at java.text.BreakIterator.getBreakInstance(BreakIterator.java:544)
                at java.text.BreakIterator.getLineInstance(BreakIterator.java:483)
                at java.text.BreakIterator.getLineInstance(BreakIterator.java:470)
                at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PlainText$Paragraph.getLines(PlainText.java:159)
                at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PlainTextFormatter.format(PlainTextFormatter.java:182)
                at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper.insertGeneratedAppearance(AppearanceGeneratorHelper.java:422)
                at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper.setAppearanceContent(AppearanceGeneratorHelper.java:288)
                at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper.setAppearanceValue(AppearanceGeneratorHelper.java:170)
                at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTextField.constructAppearances(PDTextField.java:263)
                at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTerminalField.applyChange(PDTerminalField.java:228)
                at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTextField.setValue(PDTextField.java:218)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
                at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
                at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
                at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
            at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
            at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
            at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
            at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
            at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:159)
            at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
            at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
            at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
            at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
            at sun.util.locale.provider.RuleBasedBreakIterator.readFile(RuleBasedBreakIterator.java:462)
            at sun.util.locale.provider.RuleBasedBreakIterator.readTables(RuleBasedBreakIterator.java:375)
            at sun.util.locale.provider.RuleBasedBreakIterator.<init>(RuleBasedBreakIterator.java:321)
            at sun.util.locale.provider.BreakIteratorProviderImpl.getBreakInstance(BreakIteratorProviderImpl.java:169)
            ... 76 common frames omitted
```

Now If you look at the top of the errors you can see a few ERROR messages that I have created to help identify where it goes wrong.
Now my specific code looks like :

```
InputStream template = HomeController.class.getResourceAsStream("template");
PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(template);
PDDocumentCatalog pdfCatalog = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = pdfCatalog.getAcroForm();
PDPageTree pages = pdfCatalog.getPages();    
ArrayList<String> myObjectList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<PDField> fields = acroForm.getFields();
for(int i = 0; i< firstAidList.size(); i++) {
               log.error("I="+ i + "   " + "fields=" + fields.get(i));
               fields.get(i).setValue(myObjectList.get(i));
               log.error("I="+ i + "   " + "fields=" + fields.get(i));
}
// Few more stuff done then I close
pdfDocument.close();
template.close();
```

Basically `myObjectList` is the data I get from the web form, the `fields` is the fields I get from my pdf template and in the for loop I just set them up - but if you look at the code and the first error messages the problem occurs when trying to set the 2nd value.
As it works in my eclipse but not the tomcat server(separate from the eclipse one) one of my thoughts is towards some permissions on the tomcat server but have no idea how to "prove" it.

Comment: `BreakIterator.getLineInstance();` is pure java... what is your default locale?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr - Had a look at the `BreakIterator` and seems the suggested for it restart on the tomcat server did the job. Now it works as it used to - Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the solution was to restart the tomcat server.
Related to problems with `BreakIterator` after java updates on the server.